Validate button name with partial label including a space
I am trying to click a button with the following line:
await page.getByRole('button', { name: '3 Employees' }).click();

My problem is that the name of the button changes depending on the number of employees so it will fail if the value is hardcoded. I would user a locator method with only the word 'Employees' but it will match with another button that has the same locator and the same 'Employees' text, and i also would like to avoid using a nth() method.
What i really want to do is use my line of code, but to only search for the ' Employees' part, meaning i want to include the space between 3 and 'Employees'. Or is there some way to validate the 3 as any kind of random value in this case, like a "{randomvalue} Employees" ?

as for regex you could use \d+ Employees. See: https://regex101.com/r/xoCPlV/latest

Please share a bit more context. Often, the best way to select an element depends on its parent tree and other similar elements in the document. But yes, {name: /^\d+ employees$/} may work for this particular element.

Using a regex should work for this particular button, assuming there are no other /^\d+ Employees$/ elements on the page:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button></button>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("button").textContent =
    ~~(Math.random() * 100) + " Employees";
}, 3000);
</script>
</body></html>`;

test("{n} Employees button can be clicked", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: /^\d+ Employees$/}).click();
});

Note the ^ and $ anchors, making it an exact match (other than leading/trailing whitespace). If you want to use a substring match, omit these anchors.
If there are other elements matching this, then you'll likely want to consider the parent chain to isolate a particular button rather than using first/last/nth, which you correctly want to avoid.
Finally, if there is a way to ensure the page renders a specific number of employees, I'd pursue that. I'd only use the above code if there really is no good way to operate the page in a more predictable manner.
